# Connection string for the Northwind.sdf

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I am making a small Windows application using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL server compact edition 3.5. I want to access Northwind.sdf database in my application but I am unable to make the connection string.

I have copied the database in my application as well as in the debug folder as I am trying to run application in debug mode.

Comment: What happens when you try? Any error messages? You'll get help faster by providing more information about the problem, not about how urgent it is to you.

Comment: I agree that it would be better if you provide error messages and sample code. Just the same, for troubleshooting purpose, start by having the .sdf file not on the network or program files folder as it could be permisson issue.

Comment: Sorry I was unable to reply but thanks for your support..again sorry for not providing all the details. Well I made it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have got to give us a bit more than that. First of all are you trying to connect to the database using SqlConnetion or SqlCeConnection? Secondly, are you sure that path or you database is correct? You may also referre to the links below for more info.

[Sql Compact 2008 Connection string Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990620/sql-compact-2008-connection-string-problem)

[Sql Compact Connection String](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce)

If you want any further help try to post the code you have done so far.

Comment: Sorry I was unable to reply but thanks for your support..again sorry for not providing all the details. Well I made it :)